# Specifying proxy for http-proxy-middleware

Tags: node.js, proxy, fiddler, http-proxy-middleware

I have a nodeJS project for a front-end that connects to multiple micro services.When we do final deployments we actually deploy the built JS and HTML in a WAR file along with the backend.

However, for development we use the `http-proxy-middleware` so we are able to do quick changes and edits on the front-end and see the results.

Today though, I would like to be able to see the connections leaving NODE-JS and going towards our microservices.

Specifically, I want to tunnel them through fiddler ( which is an http proxy usually running on port 8888 ).

Does anyone know to do this?

I tried setting e.g. the following but it doesn't affect the outgoing connection:

npm config set proxy http://localhost:8888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer to my problem is to `use fiddler as a reverse proxy`:

https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy

I came across it by accident partly. I thought maybe I can't intercept all requests, but I could set my endpoint as being fiddler.

I did that, and saw a response in fiddler from the `Fiddler Echo Service`.

It basically displays a page similar to:

```
Fiddler Echo Service

PUT /abc-service/initialize HTTP/1.1
accept-language: en-AU,en;q=0.9,el;q=0.8,en-NZ;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept: */*
postman-token: 0466cca5-21f9-67ab-be05-5227ef667fe4
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 0
connection: close
host: localhost:8889   
X-Tenant-Id: abc  
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Force-Http-Protocol: true
X-Forwarded-Prefix: abc-service

This page returned a HTTP/200 response 
Originating Process Information: node:15044

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
•To configure Fiddler as a reverse proxy instead of seeing this page, see Reverse Proxy Setup ( https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy )
•You can download the FiddlerRoot certificate
```

Answer (score 1):

`npm config set proxy http://localhost:8888` is used to configure NPM to download packages through a proxy.

You will need to connect to fiddler's HTTP proxy instead of your usual backend, with the relevant HTTP headers for proxying.

So a request would look something like

```
http.get ({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8888,
    path: 'http://actual.backend/url'
}, function (response) {
    console.log (response);
});
```